# React form submission with ReactDOM: does not re-render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to test a React form submission programmatically using Jest and ReactDOM.

The following is a snippet from the test code:

```js
var mycomp = <MyForm />;
var container = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(mycomp, container);

container.querySelector('#Project').value = "Test Project";
container.querySelector('#Description').innerHTML= "Test description";

// Submit the form
// (See: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6796#issuecomment-288350025)
container.querySelector('form').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));        

expect(container.querySelector('#successMessage')).not.toBeNull(); // this fails!
```

In the submit function handler I update the state, which in turn, after a re-rendering, should add a span element having "successMessage" as id.
Unfortunately, the submit handler is fired (I can see its logs on the console), but the success message span does not show up.
Why is this happening? Shouldn't updates on React components rendered with ReactDOM trigger a new rendering and update the page?

**EDIT**: see a minimal reproduction of the issue here (the Jest test that fails is at the bottom, commented out) https://codepen.io/pviotti/pen/YdKKpw

Comment: The code in question doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: edit: added the full code in codepen

Comment: I would think it's because the react component hasn't finished updating yet by the time you've searched for the element. You could set a timeout to wait for the rerender, but there's probably a better solution.